# How to create my own vpn service on linux shell?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, shell, vpn

My company has a private linux server, and I'm just a user of this server, my connection to it is via putty or nc.

Is there anyway to install a private VPN on it? our server is connected to the internet and I want to connect too by VPN from my client.

honestly I don't know anything about configuration of server and client for this purpose so if it possible, could you please tell me about it step by step.

my client is Windows XP

Thnx a lot ...

Comment: Most likely, your IT people will have configured the Linux server in such a way as to make any modification to it impossible. But accessing the Internet through the server's VPN is not impossible, but more info is needed. Can you post the output of ipconfig and your routing table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install VPN softwre. You can try to encapsulate all your trafic trhough the SSH :
http://blog.buttewifi.com/2010/01/dynamic-ssh-tunneling-with-putty-to-secure-web-traffic/